# Would this question be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, on-topic

I wanted to ask a question in this site, but I'm not sure it would be on-topic (maybe a bit opinion based):

> I'm currently an IT project manager (I have a french engineering degree in computer science and masters in finance) and I'm thinking about changing career and go to college again to become an airline pilot, but I'm worried about the possibility of finding a job after it because of the COVID - is it still possible to find a job as an airline pilot today? And a "well-payed" one?
>
> I did a lot of research on these kind of studies and the cost in my country (France) and it would be a huge investment to do it (both financially and time-consuming) so I don't want to go back to college "for nothing" (I will still be able to find a job the one I have today but it's not what I want)

So, can you tell me if this question is on topic here, or help me to make it on topic?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I asked the question on the main site, changing it a bit after @Jamiec answer. See the question here : https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/88335/airline-job-market-and-covid

Comment: I asked a [similar question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1255/65) some time ago. The pandemic has changed a lot of things but I also heard that there will be an even bigger shortage of pilots once we are out of pandemic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have certainly had a number of questions over the years on how to become a commercial pilot, so I'm not too concerned about that aspect being on topic.

The parts about this question which worry me are actually the 2 bits you put before a question mark

- Is it possible to find a job as an airline pilot?: Of course it's *possible* but there might be a lot of competition. I'm not sure how quantifyable this part of your question really is. Perhaps this part is too broad. It will depend on location, willingness to travel etc
- A "well-payed" one?: Well, this is purely opinion based. What is well-payed? Is one person's "badly paid" a job that someone else will take just to get some experience?

All in all, I'm not entirely convinced your question would be well received but there is only 1 way to find out and that is to post it. It is not entirely off-topic, and the community here will make a decision as to how appropriate they feel it is for our site.

As an aside, just remember that if you start training right now, there might be a chance that COVID restrictions (but probably not the virus itself) are a thing of the past by the time you qualify with a commercial license.

Comment: Thanks for your input, so maybe I should add more context (location & willingness to travel) and change it a bit and phrase it like: "Is it harder than before COVID?" and "Are the salaries the same as before COVID or is it less paid?". For the side note, yeah I thought about that but anticipating what it'll be in 2 years is a lot more opinion based - plus it can't be worse than today ?

Comment: @LP154 I agree with Jamiec that this may not be received well. There are a lot of different factors which can change the answer.